# How to filter by date in a WFS request?

Tags: wfs, filter, date, getfeature

I'm using the following GetFeature request to filter features by a date field. (The layer is, for testing purposes, hosted by a local GeoServer instance and its data is stored in a GeoPackage file on the file system.)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<wfs:GetFeature
    xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0"
    xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0"
    outputFormat="application/json"
>
    <wfs:Query typeNames="sf:my_layer">
        <wfs:Filter>
            <fes:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                <fes:ValueReference>myDate</fes:ValueReference>
                <fes:Literal>2024-02-27T05:08:08Z</fes:Literal>
            </fes:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
        </wfs:Filter>
    </wfs:Query>
</wfs:GetFeature>
```

This request is giving me back the following GeoJSON feature:

```json
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": "my_layer.1",
            "geometry": null,
            "geometry_name": "geometry",
            "properties": {
                "fid": 1,
                "comment": "test",
                "myDate": "2024-02-27T07:08:09Z"
            }
        }
    ],
    "totalFeatures": 1,
    "numberMatched": 1,
    "numberReturned": 1,
    "timeStamp": "2024-02-28T12:42:58.849Z",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326"
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I advance the filter date in the request by one second, as in ...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<wfs:GetFeature
    xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0"
    xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0"
    outputFormat="application/json"
>
    <wfs:Query typeNames="sf:my_layer">
        <wfs:Filter>
            <fes:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                <fes:ValueReference>myDate</fes:ValueReference>
                <fes:Literal>2024-02-27T05:08:09Z</fes:Literal>
            </fes:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
        </wfs:Filter>
    </wfs:Query>
</wfs:GetFeature>
```

..., no features are returned:

```json
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [],
    "totalFeatures": 0,
    "numberMatched": 0,
    "numberReturned": 0,
    "timeStamp": "2024-02-28T12:44:08.476Z",
    "crs": null
}
```

The same is true for every date after it.

It seems like this may be an issue concerning time zones. On the other hand, both the request and the response dates specify UTC time zone.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**

This is what I'm seeing in the `geoserver.log`:

```
29 Feb 09:29:03 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getFeature
    service = WFS
    version = 2.0.0
    baseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
    outputFormat = application/json
    resolve = none
    resolveDepth = *
    resolveTimeout = 300
    resultType = results
    abstractQueryExpressionGroup[0] = wfs:abstractQueryExpression=net.opengis.wfs20.impl.QueryTypeImpl@5a69b674 (handle: null) (abstractProjectionClause: null, abstractSelectionClause: [ myDate > 2024-02-27T05:08:09Z ], abstractSortingClause: null, aliases: null, typeNames: [{http://www.openplans.org/spearfish}my_layer]) (featureVersion: null, srsName: null, filter: null, propertyNames: null, sortBy: null)
    abstractQueryExpression[0]:
        abstractSelectionClause = [ myDate > 2024-02-27T05:08:09Z ]
        typeNames[0] = {http://www.openplans.org/spearfish}my_layer
        filter = [ myDate > 2024-02-27T05:08:09Z ]
29 Feb 09:29:03 INFO   [wfs.json] - about to encode JSON
```

Comment: Can you check the server log file? Do you have a limit or count set in the query?

Comment: I updated the post to include the log. No limit/count is set on the query.